# Run command on Command Prompt start

Tags: windows, cmd

Is there a way to run any command (eg: cd D:\test) on Command Prompt start and to have this instance of Command Prompt as a different shortcut/instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a shortcut that has a target of e.g.:

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Full_Path_to\VsDevCmd.bat""
```

Where the `.bat` file is the command(s) that you want to run on startup. This will then leave you with an open command prompt after those commands have executed.

(In case it's not obvious, this is just shamelessly ripped from one of the Developer Command Prompt shortcuts that Visual Studio installs in the Start Menu)

---

`%comspec%` is a nice way of getting `cmd` to execute.

[Cmd](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true):

> **/k** : Carries out the command specified by string and continues.

Comment: @AndriyM - I opened the shortcut properties and copied and pasted it into my answer. The only thing I've done subsequently was to remove the full path in program files since it made the actual batch file name scroll off to the right. They're there to protect spaces in the path.

Comment: Sorry, I realised only too late why they were doubled.